# 18.5.A. EXERCISE in Ravi Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

$18.5.A.$ EXERCISE (ASSUMING SERRE DUALITY). Suppose $C$ is a geometrically
integral smooth projective curve over $k$.

(a) Show that $h^0(C, \omega_C)$ is the genus $g$ of $C$.

(b) Show that $\deg \omega_C = 2g - 2$. (Hint: Riemann-Roch for $\mathcal{L} = \omega_C$.)

For item b), just take item a) and apply Riemann-Roch + Serre Duality along with the hint. So:

$h^0(C, \mathcal{L})-h^0(C, \omega_C \otimes \mathcal{L}^\vee)=\text {deg} \mathcal{L}-g +1$ and do $\mathcal{L}=\omega_c  \Rightarrow$

$ \Rightarrow h^0(C, \omega_C)-h^0(C, \omega_C \otimes \omega_C^{\vee})=\deg\omega_C -g +1$.

Like for a geometrically integral projective variety, $h^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C=\omega_C \otimes \omega_C^{\vee}) = 1$, then

$h^0(C, \omega_C)=\deg \omega_C -g +2$. And by item a): $\deg \omega_C=2g-2.$

How to proceed to show item a)? That's my problem.

Comment: Step 1: write down the statement of Serre duality. How can you make $h^0(C,\omega_C)$ show up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the definition of genus to a integral
projective curves $C$ over an algebraically closed field, we have to:

$g=p_a(C):=h^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C)=h^0(C, \mathcal{O}_{C}^{\vee}\otimes \omega_{C})=h^0(C, \mathcal{O}_{C}\otimes \omega_{C})=h^0(C,\omega_{C}).$